# Which version of eclipse IDE is compatible with the java 10?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to install Eclipse java ee IDE , and java 10 is already installed on system. So which version of Eclipse java ee IDE is compatible with java 10?

Comment: have you tried oxygen?

Comment: You need Eclipse Oxygen to use Java 9/10, though you *might* be able to get it running on Neon if you have the right plugins (not sure if they work now).

Comment: eclipse oxygen can be used for this.

Comment: Use the latest version (Photon) [which was released last week](http://www.eclipse.org/photon/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Photon should be compatible with Java 10.

Answer (score 3):

The first version of Eclipse with full support for using Java 10 features was Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a).

Since then Eclipse Photon (4.8) has been released and became the recommended version for Java 10.

It is recommended that you always install the most up to date version of Eclipse available (Eclipse 2022-12 at the time of writing).